# Lucene search not working for string number combimation java

Tags: java, performance, lucene

I am trying to search data using lucene indexing.I am using KeywordTokenizerFactory and LowerCaseFilterFactory I am trying to get record with name "police name 25423" ,I am not getting data. If I try with "police" or "name" or "25423" or"police name" separately then I am getting result.Why with full name not able to get result?.

Answer (score 1):

Problem because you use KeywordTokenizerFactory. In this case,  Lucene will search documents with term "police name 25423". You should change tokenizer factory to StandardTokenizerFactory,  in this case you will be search documents with terms "police" "name" "25423".

Answer (score 0):

Is there any record exits with all three words in the same query??

First Check that.

Comment: Yes record with name "police name 25423" exsists

Comment: in the same field in which you are searching?? post the query here.